# DropDownlist showing in every textfield of cell swift

Tags: ios, swift

I made a custom `UITextField` which shows a 'dropdownMenu'. But what is happening is if I write in `textField`, then every `textfield` of Cell suddenly starts showing the dropdown. And there is also one other issue. I have a `textfield` in `stackView`. And this `stackView` is in `CardView` (used for shadow). And this `CardView` is in Cell. How can I add this `suggestionTable` inside cell instead of using `super.super.super.super.addSuView(suggestionTable)` to add In cell

```
open class SuggestionTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

var identifier = "SuggestionCell"
var suggestionTable:UITableView!
var suggestionlist = ["First","Second","Third","Four","Fifth","Sixth","Seven","eight","Nine","Ten"]
var filterSuggestionlist = [String]()
var heightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!
var defaultShow = true {
    didSet {
        self.suggestionTable.reloadData()
    }
}

convenience init() {
    self.init(
        frame: CGRect.zero)
    self.delegate = self
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(filterSuggestions), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidChange, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.delegate = self
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(filterSuggestions), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidChange, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {

    let keyboardFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    guard let frame = self.superview?.convert(self.frame, to: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow) else { return }
    //guard let frame = self.superview?.convert(self.frame, to: nil) else { return }
    let gap = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - frame.origin.y - frame.height - keyboardFrame.height)
    guard suggestionTable != nil else {
        return
    }
    heightConstraint.constant = gap
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
}

func filterSuggestions(){
    self.setup()
    if (self.text?.isEmpty)! {
        self.defaultShow = true
        return
    }

    filterSuggestionlist = suggestionlist.filter({ (suggestion) -> Bool in
        return suggestion.contains(self.text!)
    })
    self.defaultShow = false
}

func setup(){

    guard suggestionTable == nil else {
        return
    }
    suggestionTable = UITableView()
    suggestionTable.allowsSelection = true
    suggestionTable.dataSource = self
    suggestionTable.delegate = self
    suggestionTable.estimatedRowHeight = 40
    suggestionTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   // suggestionTable.layer.masksToBounds = false
   // suggestionTable.clipsToBounds = false
    suggestionTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    suggestionTable.separatorStyle  = .none
    suggestionTable.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    suggestionTable.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    suggestionTable.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 3)
    suggestionTable.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    suggestionTable.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    suggestionTable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    suggestionTable.register(suggestionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.addSubview(suggestionTable)
    superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: suggestionTable)
    setupConstrain()
}

func setupConstrain(){

    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: suggestionTable, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let rightConstraint =  NSLayoutConstraint(item:
        suggestionTable, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: suggestionTable, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 2)
    heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: suggestionTable, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leftConstraint, rightConstraint, topConstraint, heightConstraint])
}

func removeSuggestionView(){

    guard suggestionTable != nil else {
        return
    }
    suggestionTable.removeFromSuperview()
    suggestionTable = nil

}

public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.setup()
}

public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    removeSuggestionView()
}

public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    _  = self.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

}

extension SuggestionTextField : UITableViewDelegate ,UITableViewDataSource {

public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return defaultShow ? suggestionlist.count : filterSuggestionlist.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! suggestionCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = defaultShow ? suggestionlist[indexPath.row] : filterSuggestionlist[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    return cell
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.text = defaultShow ? suggestionlist[indexPath.row] : filterSuggestionlist[indexPath.row]
    if !self.defaultShow {
        self.defaultShow = !self.defaultShow
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
}
```

[image: This What happended if write something on textField]

Thanks!!

Comment: i think because you all your text filed have Observer to keyboard Show and dismiss and in every observer you call setup()

Comment: I Solved it. It is because of 'UITextField' textChange Observer. i moved that one into becomeFirstResponder() and it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you set resignFirstResponder() in textfield or set becomeFirstResponder() to control easy at textfield other.

Comment: Any solution for second Problem?